# scanf with %d doesn't stop for input

Tags: c, scanf

I have a small program that uses `scanf` to block the program :

```
int main (void)
{
    stdout = stdin = &uart_str;
    int i = 0;

    while(1) {
        scanf("%d",&i);
        readMeasurement();
    }
```

The problem that I have is that the program is not stopping at the `scanf`. I'm using Atmel Studio and the UART for the input and output.

Any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: What is `uart_str`? Have you checked what is actually being sent to your program? Have you checked what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns? What does `readMeasurement` do, does it read as well?

Comment: scanf will read any new lines, spaces etc. Can you trace what is being received? Perhaps try scanf to a file for anything received.

Comment: I use the Arduino environment and I didn't understand why printf/scanf doesn't run correctly. Using Arduino I prefer to use Serial.read() together Serial.available() in a function that collects the chars and then I convert the acquired string. However, I would like to know how to use such a functions!

Comment: @Joshpbarron not with `%d`, it will not read newlines and spaces.

Comment: Can you show how you use your program and how you know the program doesn't stop at `scanf` ?

Comment: @Eregrith `scanf` with the `"%d"` format will read and discard leading *whitespace*, so it may indeed read newlines and space.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg as in "consume"?

Comment: I solved my issue on AVR ATMega168. The problem is probably that the console you're using to send strings to the AVR doesn't send the CR (carriage return). I've set my console to send the CR and the scanf runs!

Comment: If you have linux SO, you may use the command `screen /dev/ttyACM1 115200' to interface the MCU where /dev/ttyACM1 have to be substituted with the serial connected to the micro and 115200 have to be substituted with the baudrate you are using. Using screen the CR is sent and the scanf runs! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this below

edit from `scanf("%d",&i);` to `scanf(" %d",&i);`

(insert space in front of `%d` )

Comment: Won't change anything. `%d` already skips whitespace characters.